# Content hides behind header after used HTML anchor tag

Tags: html, css, scroll

I just have a little problem here that i cannot fix it.

I am doing an one page website, I have 3 links on my navig bar, as soon as I click in one of them it should scroll down to a especific div, and IT DOES. But now it goes behind the fixed header I set.

HTML

```
<div class="header1">
            .... blablabla...
</div>

        <div class="navigbox">
            <div class="navig">
                <a href="#intro">About</a>  
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="intro">                
                some text
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.header1{
    height: 20%; width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top: 0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;}

.navigbox{
    background: white;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 10%; width: 80%;
    left: 10%;
    top: 20%;}  

.navig{
    height: 100%; width: 33.33%;
    float:letf;}    

#intro{
    background: white;
    height: 60%; width: 70%;
    left: 10%;
    top: 30%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 5% 5% 0 5%;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the height of the header isn't considered when the page scrolls. Instead of applying the `id` to the `div` itself, put another element, say an `a`, before it and seperate the two with a couple `br`'s.

Edit: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26476867/1070107) has a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to George's answer, you could add the space you need by applying margin to the top of the first element inside your `div`s.  That way you don't need any extra elements.  It's going to be tricky to get it exactly the way you have it though because padding %, both top/bottom and left/right, is computed relative to the width of the parent, whereas height % is obviously relative to the parent's height.

Comment: That's actually probably a better way to go than what I said.

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS the other elements are overlapping the header1 because they have a higher or equal z-index. Set the z-index of header 1 higher rather than one